# IsArchived field isn't available on the CollaborationGroup object. Why is this?

Tags: apex, chatter, query, chatter-groups

I have a list of all Chatter Groups in my org, I want to stop any archived chatter groups from displaying in this list.

So I want to check for the `IsArchived` field and if `true`, don't display it.

I'm trying the following query:

```
List<CollaborationGroup> collaborationGroups = [select Id, Name, IsArchived from CollaborationGroup where Id in :collaborationGroupIds ORDER BY NAME ASC LIMIT 200];
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
No such column 'IsArchived' on entity 'CollaborationGroup'
```

If I remove `IsArchived` from the query, it runs fine.

According to the [SF docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_collaborationgroup.htm), there definitely is an `IsArchived` field on the `CollaborationGroup` object.

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What API version are you using? The IsArchived field is only available in v28.0 and higher. I'll get this information added to the docs that you cited.

Comment: The docs say 19. I'm using 27 i think, just left the office so can't be 100% sure right now.

Comment: I work at Salesforce and have submitted a doc bug to have it corrected. In addition, the IsAutoArchiveDisabled field is available in v29.0 and higher.

Comment: Ah I see. Cheers for the assistance.

Comment: @alouie I noticed in answering [the same question on StackOverflow](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter14/release-notes/rn_186_api_chatter.htm) that the Winter '14 release notes include this change, which is API v29.0.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I was able to use v28.0 to query for IsArchived in my org -- I think the feature was being piloted in Summer '13, which is why it's available in the release prior to the GA release of Winter '14.